# PyQt6 Setting custom rect in QSlider's paintEvent

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt

How can I make QSlider's paintEvent's rect a little smaller? I want to have a really thin slider but I want it to be able to receive clicks easily so it's actual size has to be a bit bigger than what's painted. If the slider is really thin, 2 pixels for example, it's so annoying to try and catch the handle or click on it. I tried creating custom QPaintEvent within `paintEvent` method and making it's rect height equal to 1-2 and then passing it to `super().paintEvent(my_new_paint_event)` but it didn't work. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides using a QSS (which requires to style *all* properties), the only reliable solution is to use a proxy style.

While overriding the `paintEvent()` of the slider is possible, there are two main issues:

- changing the event region is completely pointless, as it will only change the exposed region that the function will draw upon (and that region might also be completely ignored);
- the default `paintEvent()` of QSlider updates its option based on the current state and active/hovered subcontrols before calling the style functions, and unless you're willing to override a bunch of other functions (enter/leave, mouse press/move/release, keyboard events, etc), you'll only get a partially working result that won't reflect the actual widget state;

A QSlider draws itself using the [`drawComplexControl()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawComplexControl) function of QStyle, and this is achieved by providing a set of flags used for the `subControls` and `activeSubControls` of [QStyleOptionSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyleoptionslider.html).

Since one of those controls is `SC_SliderGroove`, which is the part of the slider on which the handle moves, the solution is to remove that from the `subControls`, and do the painting on your own. Remember that painting happens from bottom to top, so the custom groove must be drawn *before* calling the base implementation.

```py
class Style(QtWidgets.QProxyStyle):
    def drawComplexControl(self, control, opt, qp, widget=None):
        if control == self.CC_Slider:
            # get the default rectangle of the groove
            groove = self.subControlRect(
                control, opt, self.SC_SliderGroove, widget)
            # create a small one
            if opt.orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                rect = QtCore.QRectF(
                    groove.x(), groove.center().y() - .5, 
                    groove.width(), 2)
            else:
                rect = QtCore.QRectF(
                    groove.center().x() - .5, groove.y(), 
                    2, groove.height())
            qp.save()
            qp.setBrush(opt.palette.mid())
            qp.setPen(opt.palette.dark().color())
            qp.setRenderHints(qp.Antialiasing)
            qp.drawRoundedRect(rect, 1, 1)
            qp.restore()

            # remove the groove flag from the subcontrol list
            opt.subControls &= ~self.SC_SliderGroove

        super().drawComplexControl(control, opt, qp, widget)
```

<sup>The above is generic for PyQt5 and PySide, for PyQt6 you need to change the flag names using their type, like `Qt.Orientation.Horizontal`, etc.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I managed to do it, although now I'm facing a different problem and am in need of advice. Slider and it's sub controls should change color when I call a certain method (light mode or dark mode). I have a stylesheet for both light and dark mode but applying them overwrites the changes the proxy style made. What would be an elegant solution to this problem? Here's what my stylesheets look like: [https://pastebin.com/S6JEJgRr](https://pastebin.com/S6JEJgRr).

Comment: Style sheets are *not* compatible with QStyle. If you want to use QSS with complex widgets, you have to change **all** properties (meaning that the above becomes useless). See [Customizing QSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider).

Comment: So then, should I do the same thing like above for every sub control of QSlider I want to modify (handle, addPage, subPage)? What I'm worried about is, how would I change colors then? Does QStyleOptionComplex inherit palette from QSlider, so it would be as simple as using palette colors in draw methods and changing palette in QSlider?

Comment: No: the problem is that whenever you set specific properties of a complex widget, the QStyle is completely bypassed and ignored. In your case, the issue happens by setting `:handle`. As said above, QStyle are *not* compatible with style sheets, so if you want to use those, you have to follow what's explained in the link above. Start with those examples and play around with that.

Comment: So if I want to have custom style, I can't use stylesheets, is what you're saying? Then do I have to manually draw in QProxyStyle everything I want to change, for example if I want the handle to be thinner, and I can't use style sheets, do I have to draw it by using sub controls in my style? I'm sorry if I'm kinda slow to figure it out, I used style sheets for a very long time and am only starting to learn about styles.

Comment: Not exactly. The documentation [specifically says](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#creating-a-custom-style) (see at the end of that section) "Qt style sheets are currently not supported for custom QStyle subclasses. We plan to address this in some future release". While this is has to be considered the general rule, the situation is a bit more complex: there is some level of support, but it's very limited and changes depending on the widget and the properties; generally speaking, for complex widgets like QSlider, you either use a QProxyStyle, or you use style sheets.

Comment: Note that if you just want to make the groove smaller, then you can easily do that with QSS, but, as already said, you then have to set *all* other properties. Just follow the examples linked above to learn how they work.